# Who was or what is Týn in Prague?

Tags: terminology, identify-this, prague

In Prague there is the church of [Our Church of Our Lady before Týn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_of_Our_Lady_before_T%C3%BDn).

I have been to the city a couple of times and I am still wondering who Týn was, or what the word means. I only found a Czech entry in Wikipedia but not sure of what it says.

Answer (score 13):

As the English Wikipedia page says, "Týn" is the name of a nearby courtyard visited by merchants. Jonathan Reez points out that "Týn" itself is [an archaic word for a fence](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Slavic/tyn%D1%8A). In this case, "before" probably means "in front of" (for example, as in "He appeared before the judge"), rather than "earlier in time than", though the church is actually older than the courtyard.

Wikipedia sources its claim about the name to a [Czech web page](http://www.tyn.cz/cz/index.php?stranka=historie-20100201) which [Google translates](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tyn.cz%2Fcz%2Findex.php%3Fstranka%3Dhistorie-20100201&edit-text=&act=url) as (in part):

> The most important religious building right bank of the Vltava is undoubtedly the Old Town church of Our Lady before Tyn, called the Tyn Church. Was named after the otýněného [I guess Google doesn't know how to translate that word] or fenced place, Tyn courtyard, which is also called Ungeld. This court has served since the mid-13th century, foreign merchants, who came here to spend the night and then paying duty. The church of the Virgin Mary is older, the former is mentioned together with a hospital 1135.

Comment: The German word "Dun" means fence, and its English cognate "town" previously meant a walled settlement. Could this be a Germanic loanword or even a pure Slavic cognate?

Comment: @RobertColumbia The Wiktionary page I linked says it's from proto-Germanic, so the answer to your question seems to be essentially yes.

Comment: @RobertColumbia the word 'town' comes from the same proto-word.

Comment: The translation is bad. A word for word one keeping the meaning would be "Church of the mother of god in front of Týn". Also as far as I can tell "Týnský dvůr" is much older then the current version of the Church which comes from the 14th. century, whereas "Týnský dvůr" was what seems to have amounted to a form of customs checkpoint for Prague already in the 11.th. There was an older Roman style church at the same place for which the earliest documentation is from 1135 so still probably younger than "Týnský dvůr".

Comment: @DRF But, in certain types of formal English, "before" does mean "in front of": I give an example of this exact thing in my answer!

Comment: While before can mean "in front of" when used with some verbs such as "appear" I think in modern english at least this is restricted to uses where whatever you're appearing in front of is an entity. So you can "appear before" a judge, magistrate even your boss. But you would have trouble "appearing before" a church, river or table unless you were there earlier in time or they were anthropomorphized. I will try and check the BYU corpuses (corpi?)(bah corpora) for collocates.

Comment: So having taken a look at the corpora I did leave out the possibility of appearing before a group of people "court,panel, congress, commission" and "someones eyes". But it turns out that while it's quite rare "before the church" in the sense of "in front of" does actually appear as well. It's fairly rare 2 "before the church *" with the in front of meaning compared to 80ish "in front of"  but it does exist. Still I would claim that using the "before" translation is confusing at best unidiomatic or wrong at worst.

Comment: @DRF correct the Wiki article then? :)

Comment: Sure, but we're not dealing with modern English. We're dealing with the traditional name of a church, and the church often uses formalized and somewhat stylized, somewhat archaic language. As a native speaker, I think the translation is actually fine.

Comment: @RobertColumbia can you cite a dictionary that lists *Dun* as a German word for "fence"?  I can find nothing, but the best dictionary I have on my shelf is an etymological dictionary.  Is it an archaic or regional form of *Zaun?*

Comment: @DRF exact phrase searches yield many results for things like "stand before the throne," "stand before the gate," "stand before the door," etc.  Scanning the results does lead to the conclusion that in most of these "...before the..." does in fact mean "...in front of the..."; and, indeed, most of these instances appear in an archaic or religious context.

Comment: @phoog I understand. But the Czech version has no special religious or archaic connotations. Týn is just a place name. It's stripped of meaning (eventhough the etymology for Týn according to the wiktionary https://cs.wiktionary.org/wiki/t%C3%BDn does come from old slavonic tynъ meaning a wall originally from old german masculine *tūna-z) But this meaning is fully lost now in the Czech language with only a derivative of it existing in the Moravian dialect meaning a plank (týňka). All together I agree before has a spatial meaning but I don't think it's a good translation of "před" in this name.

Comment: @DRF The point is that it would have been a natural translation a couple of hundred years ago so it remains appropriate today because the Christian church often uses this kind of slightly archaic language. (And it may actually have been the English name of the church for a couple of hundred years.) If the church were in an English city, it could easily be called the Church of Our Lady before the Town (or before the Something Else).

Comment: Your versions have a definite article before the noun that wouldn't work in this case. I'm sorry as a person who understands both the Czech and English version Church of our lady before Týn sounds bloody awful and doesn't translate the meaning well. Church of Our Lady before the Town sounds fine. I'm not gonna argue the point any more though.

Answer (score 10):

I'll add to David Richerby's answer. Translating from [Czech Wikipedia](https://cs.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%C3%BDn_(Praha)), Týn (also Týnský dvůr, meaning "Týn Yard") was a fenced in and moated trader's yard where traders had to pay a toll ("Ungelt" in old German, which is also the alternative name) for protection.

I do not know about the meaning of the word Týn, but the fence explanation given by David Richerby sounds plausible. To me, as a native speaker, the word Týn doesn't really carry any meaning.

Finally, "před Týnem" means "in front of Týn".

Comment: Thanks for "in front of" -- that's the phrase I was looking for! (Not because I was trying to translate the Czech but just a vague general feeling that "before" is used for other situations other than time. You saying "in front of" reminded me of another example from English, which is to "appear before a court", which I've added to my answer.)

Comment: To me, as a native speaker of another Slavic language, the word "tyn" is not completely unknown, because it is occasionally met in folk songs. However, as an urban kid I was never sure about its meaning; I only knew that was something rustic.